# Управление глагола «следовать»

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы, управление

Глагол «следовать» ставит существительное в дательный падеж: *следовать (чему?) правилам*. При другом его значении появляется предлог «за» и, соответственно, творительный падеж: *следовать за кем-то/чем-то*.

В одной книге автор (наш современник) упорно и довольно часто употребляет такие выражения, в которых этот глагол выступает как бы синонимом глагола «руководствоваться»: *следует традици**ей***, *следует правд**ой*** и пр., например:

> Надел Попович «шелом греческий», поскольку **следовал не ведической традицией**, а пришлой византийской.
> В архиве вечности хранится *правда истинная* о пройденных этапах вселенной. Этой **правдой и следует** ведическая Русь.

В Нацкорпусе таких примеров нет. Вообще, автор очень самобытный. К примеру, не приемлет приставку «бес», очень почитает Даля и его словарь.

Можно ли объяснить такое использование вышеупомянутого глагола? Можно ли сделать скидку на своеобразное авторское прочтение? Есть ли истоки такого феномена в истории языка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Творительный падеж без предлога возможен в контексте *дороги* и её аналогов.

> Макдональд приказал войскам, которые еще не отбыли в Вильжюиф,
> *следовать дорогой* в Сен-Дени.

*(Луи-Адольф Тьер, История Консульства и Империи)*

Такое словосочетание часто встречается в религиозных текстах ("следовать дорогой веры в Бога, дорогой нищеты Иисуса" и т. п.).

Сочетание "следует традицией" ("следует правдой") возможно, но при управлении от другого слова (напр.: "восхищаться *следует традицией* устраивать парады, а не бранить её"), - в контексте назидания.

Comment: Александр. Спасибо. Я в вопрос добавил предложения. Можно ли в таком контексте рассматривать "правду" и "традицию" в качестве переносного значения пути (дороги), принципов, верований? Или творительный падеж здесь всё-таки возникает от индивидуальных особенностей восприятия автора и с точки зрения языка это ошибка?

Comment: Я воспрнимаю такие предложения как ошибку ("дорогой правды" - вполне можно было бы).

Answer (score 1):

В словаре Ушакова четвертое значение, как раз такое, но падеж дательный.

4. Следовать
   перен., чему. Руководиться чем-н., сообразовываться с чем-н. в своих действиях (книжн.). Следовать моде. Следовать прихоти. Следовать велениям долга. Следовать внушению сердца. Следовать правилам.

|| кому-чему. руководиться в каких-н. действиях чьими-н. наставлениями, чьим-н. образцом, примером, чьей-н. системе (книжн.). Следовать учению Дарвина. Во всем следовал своему отцу.

СЛЕДОВАТЬ
Следовать следовать (поступать подобно кому-л., руководствоваться чьим-л. примером) кому-чему и за кем-чем. Во всем следуйте этим людям (за этими людьми). Следовать советам врача. Следуйте всегда внушениям вашего сердца... (Тургенев). Да, смешные это люди, как Рахметов... Не следуйте за ними, благородные люди... потому что скуден личными радостями путь, на который они зовут вас (Чернышевский). Пунктуация и управление в русском языке Д.Э. Розенталь

Comment: V.V., спасибо. Это всё понятно.Просто вопрос в другом.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: ау!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Вы про мультифору? :) Ответил там – в рожке-совке-лопатке-ложке.